# Transform QR Code image into Base64 representation of itself

Tags: encryption, qr-code

I have the following qr code:
https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/110/611/748/348/381/359/original/2845afd0827a1cfd.png

Which I'd like to transform directly to base64,
so I can then use said base64 via this code

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qrcodejs/1.0.0/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="qrcode"></div>
  <script>
    const base64String = "MTIzNA==";
    const qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode", {
      text: base64String,
      width: 256,
      height: 256,
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

How do I do this ?

(All tools to decipher it result in gibberish..)

(Zgnix will give
40 0b 94 95 04 25 a0 00   18 6a 06 36 46 06 26 26
06 05 46 30 09 20 c0 ce   a0 14 08 2c 54 98 68 1c
1a 58 a0 10 e6 c9 4a f7   38 13 08 c6 d2 f3 97 3d
62 a4 30 15 10 61 cc 0b   e0 1b bb 81 d5 0d c5 ef
07 5a bd d3 a9 16 a7 43   98 78 2c 5d 79 df 98 03
44 ce dc c9 9b 38 09 4c   08 61 79 66 69 94 76 f5
f6 9f 91 2e 23 0f 15 39   51 b4 86 cc 15 73 b0 ef
3c b5 f2 21 26 e5 aa b7   0a ab db 9c b2 0e 09 15
89 29 c9 19 99 71 e9 09   ae 79 39 99 e5 10 23 2e
13 f1 0d 87 e3 dd 46 fe   b7 3e 6a cc 30 2a c0 e1
25 8e ac fe 0b 8f 26 13   42 bb fe a9 1e 48 fb 74
b3 c7 1f 90 80 6f ef ff   f7 70 90 00 ec 11 ec 11
ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11   ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11
ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11

as result.. but good luck getting the original qr back from there.)

Comment: I want the raw data stored in this qr code. How is this possibly *not* related to en/decryption. Why ever whould I want to encode a image-of-a-qr-code within another qrcode ???

Answer (score 0):

I used this to "decode" the qr (added in a "base64 option")

[Demo](https://codepen.io/ryedai1/pen/QWJpQON)

Sadly it *still* doesn't translate well to the example in the op.
If I put the now created base64 in there, it creates -yet another very removed from the original content- qr code...

*sigh*

```
<div>
  <img id="image" src="https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/110/611/748/348/381/359/original/2845afd0827a1cfd.png" width="20%" />
  <div id="result"></div>
  <form>
    <label for="file">Select an image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
    <br>
    <label for="input">Or enter a URL or text:</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" value="https://files.mastodon.social/media_attachments/files/110/611/748/348/381/359/original/2845afd0827a1cfd.png">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="base64" name="base64" value="true">
    <label for="base64">Output result as base64</label>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="decode()">Decode</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="copyResult()">Copy Output</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
function decode() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.src = e.target.result;
    qrcode.callback = function(r){
      if (document.getElementById("base64").checked) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Decode result is: ' + btoa(r);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Decode result is: ' + r;
      }
    }
    qrcode.decode(e.target.result);
  };
  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    qrcode.callback = function(r){
      if (document.getElementById("base64").checked) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Decode result is: ' + btoa(r);
      } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Decode result is: ' + r;
      }
    }
    qrcode.decode(input);
  }
}

function copyResult() {
  var result = document.getElementById("result").innerText;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(result).then(function() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = "Copied!";
  }, function() {
    console.error("Failed to copy result to clipboard.");
  });
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/grid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/version.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/detector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/formatinf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/errorlevel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/bitmat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/datablock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/bmparser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/datamask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/rsdecoder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/gf256poly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/gf256.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/decoder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/findpat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/alignpat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode/master/src/databr.js"></script>
```